# Access wrapped request web method from web service in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, json

I have a web service method taking multiple parameters.
Therefor the BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped is set.
I want to access this method from a web service client therefor I did add the url of the service method to Reference->Add Services and I get the following error.

"There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8080/Api/StoreI'.

The request failed with HTTP status 405: Method Not Allowed.

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8080/Api/StoreI'.

The content type application/json of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8).

If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.

The first 323 bytes of the response were: '{"ErrorCode":110,"ErrorDetails":null,"Message":"The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'.

This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details."}'.

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again."

What should I do in order to resolve this error?
What are the steps to access a secure web service from a client?
I an new to web services.
A reply would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert but change
 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped 
to
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare

The usage of the wrapped on the operation description does not add a layer of security on the message body. It simply wraps the request (or the response) in an XML element

Comment: but for the web service methods that take multiple parameters , the should BodyStyle  should be mentioned as wrapped otherwise the service gives an error.